# How to enable the snapping for a layer with the tolerance value with python programming

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a vector polygon and vector polyline layer. I want to enable the snapping for both the layer with tolerance value? How can i do that using python programming. I have tried this code but getting the following error:

```
snapper = QgsMapCanvasSnapper(canvas) 
snapper.setSnapSettingsForLayer(aLayer,True,SnapToVertexAndSegment,pixels,0.0001‌​,True)
```

***Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in  AttributeError: 'QgsMapCanvasSnapper' object has no attribute 'setSnapSettingsForLayer'***

Can anyone help me in setting the snapping options to the currentLayer using python programming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define it first:

```
result3 = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "ligne", "memory") 
#it's to create your layer

ligneid=result3.id()
# it allows you to have the idvalue for your layer

QgsProject.instance().setSnapSettingsForLayer(ligneid,True,2,1,1000,True)
# it defines the snapping options ligneid : the id of your layer, True : to enable the layer snapping, 2 : options (0: on vertex, 1 on segment, 2: vertex+segment), 1: pixel (0: type of unit on map), 1000 : tolerance, true : avoidIntersection)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using QGIS 3.22.16.
I created a new QgsSnappingConfig() and used setIndividualLayerSettings to add each Layer to my selection. Then I assign the config to the project instance.

```
snapping_config = QgsSnappingConfig() 
snapping_config.setEnabled(True)
snapping_config.setMode(QgsSnappingConfig.AdvancedConfiguration)
snapping_config.setIndividualLayerSettings(self.gebauedelayer, QgsSnappingConfig.IndividualLayerSettings(True, QgsSnappingConfig.VertexFlag, 10, QgsTolerance.Pixels))
snapping_config.setIndividualLayerSettings(self.flurlayer, QgsSnappingConfig.IndividualLayerSettings(True, QgsSnappingConfig.VertexFlag, 10, QgsTolerance.Pixels))
QgsProject.instance().setSnappingConfig(snapping_config)`
```