# How to Enable/Disable Topological Editing Programatically

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, toolbar

Is there a way to enable or disable topological editing with python in QGIS?
I'm trying to set a bunch of rules, one of them being the editing, when starting up a project, but I can't seem to find how to enable this.
For that matter, there's even no

```
iface.SnapppingToolBar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following to enable snapping and then topological editing (it happens at `QgsProject` level):

```py
new_conf = QgsSnappingConfig(QgsProject.instance().snappingConfig())
new_conf.setEnabled(True)
QgsProject.instance().setSnappingConfig(new_conf)
QgsProject.instance().setTopologicalEditing(True)
```

You may also look at this related question [How to enable/disable snapping functionality with PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195959/how-to-enable-disable-snapping-functionality-with-pyqgis) that mention `QgsSnappingUtils` class to ease manipulation of snapping editing configuration